# Add Nodes to Material with Python

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, scripting, node-editor

I have edited a script that creates some nodes, but the only problem is, it always created a new material. I want it to either add the nodes on the existing material, or a pre-defined material. Here is the script base I am using.

http://blenderscripting.blogspot.com.es/2013/06/automatic-colour-ramped-shader-from.html

Thanks for the help in advance! :D

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can get the material node tree from `bpy.data.materials['MyMaterial'].node_tree`

Then add the nodes with [`node_tree.nodes.new()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.types.Nodes.html?highlight=nodes.new#bpy.types.Nodes.new)

For example, to add a diffuse shader node to `MyMaterial` and create `MyMaterial` if it doesn't exist:

```
import bpy
mat_name = "MyMaterial"
# Test if material exists
# If it does not exist, create it:
mat = (bpy.data.materials.get(mat_name) or 
       bpy.data.materials.new(mat_name))

# Enable 'Use nodes':
mat.use_nodes = True
nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes

# Add a diffuse shader and set its location:    
node = nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')
node.location = (100,100)
```

Comment: For an example on using nodes from python, heres a script the FBX importer uses to setup a nodetree: http://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender-addons.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/io_scene_fbx/cycles_shader_compat.py

Comment: +1 for the `# Enable 'Use nodes':` tip! I was so confused why I can't refer to the `node_tree` attribute.

Answer (score 24):

The answer provided is only partially helpful. Or it is outdated in 2.7

Yes you have to add the nodes (`use_nodes = True`). However the default material is the Diffuse BSDF. So if you want to use this, fine, you're done.
But to change the shader being used:

1. Remove the shader in place (Diffuse BSDF, otherwise the second element in the `material.node_tree.nodes.values()` list. This is sort of optional, as it can also stay in place, but it's just not tidy and confusing to leave it there.
2. Create a new shader node. e.g. `material.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeEmission')`
3. Update the link to the `Material Output` node.
   `material.node_tree.links.new(mat.inputs[0], node.outputs[0])`

Here an example I made I use quite often: a Mesh Light

```
    def create_light():
        """
        Add a mesh light for cycles
        """

        # Add new plane
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(location=(15, -5, 5))
        plane = bpy.context.active_object
        plane.name = 'Light Plane'
        plane.scale = mathutils.Vector((4, 4, 4))
        # tilt
        plane.rotation_euler.rotate_axis('Y', radians(40))

        # Create a new material
        material = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Plane Light Emission Shader")
        material.use_nodes = True

        # Remove default
        material.node_tree.nodes.remove(material.node_tree.nodes.get('Diffuse BSDF'))
        material_output = material.node_tree.nodes.get('Material Output')
        emission = material.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeEmission')
        emission.inputs['Strength'].default_value = 5.0

        # link emission shader to material
        material.node_tree.links.new(material_output.inputs[0], emission.outputs[0])

        # set activer material to your new material
        plane.active_material = material
```

Comment: Your this code snippet is very helpful Sir. Thank you so much! Took me a while to figure out that link. Then I remember I saw your answer before.

Comment: Color can be set analog to Strength: `emission.inputs['Color'].default_value = (0,1,0,1)  # green RGBA`

Answer (score 3):

now at first you have principled BSDF. a variation with a diffuse node on active object

```
import bpy

# Create a new material
material = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Diffuse")
material.use_nodes = True

# Remove default
material.node_tree.nodes.remove(material.node_tree.nodes.get('Principled BSDF')) #title of the existing node when materials.new
material_output = material.node_tree.nodes.get('Material Output')
diffuse = material.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')    #name of diffuse BSDF when added with shift+A


diffuse.inputs['Color'].default_value = (1, 0, 1, 1) #last value alpha

# link diffuse shader to material
material.node_tree.links.new(material_output.inputs[0], diffuse.outputs[0])

# set activer material to your new material
bpy.context.object.active_material = material
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is. It picks up a material if it exists, else creates a new one with that name.

```
import bpy

mat_name = "MyMaterial"
materials = bpy.data.materials

# if .get returns None, the assignment comes from the right of the 'or'
mat = materials.get(mat_name) or materials.new(mat_name)   # *** see comment
mat.use_nodes = True
nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes

# Add a diffuse shader and set its location:    
node = nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')
node.location = (100,100)
```

---

I expected this to work, but it doesn't.

```
mat = materials.get(mat_name, materials.new(mat_name))
```

Comment: mat = materials.get(materials.new(mat_name).name)

Comment: cool if that works :)