# Example of creating and setting a Cycles material node with the Python API

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, scripting, materials

I'm trying to set the properties of a `Cycles` material, which is linked to a `Plane` object, using the API.

So far this is what I've got:

1. Create a floor plane object:

   ```
   bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(radius=3, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0))

   my_floor = bpy.data.objects["Plane"]
   ```
2. Create the material for my floor, (I'm assuming it does not already exist):

   ```
   my_floors_material_name = "Material"

   #create the materials object
   my_floors_material_object =    bpy.data.materials.new(my_floors_material_name)

   #Enable 'Use nodes':
   my_floors_material_object.use_nodes = True
   ```
3. Add a new node type from the list `[types.ShaderNode][1]`. I'd like to
   choose the equivalent of `node_groups["Shader Nodetree"].nodes["Anisotropic BSDF"]`:

   ```
   #create the input node
   shinny_floor_input_node = my_floors_material_nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfAnisotropic')

   #create the output node
   shinny_floor_output_node = my_floors_material_nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeOutputMaterial') 

   #link the input and output nodes, on the node tree of my object
       my_floors_material_object.node_tree.links.new(shinny_floor_input_node.outputs[0], shinny_floor_output_node.inputs[0])


   #this runs and returns 
   bpy.data.node_groups['Shader Nodetree']...NodeLink
   ```
4. Assign the floor material to the floor object:

   ```
   #assign the material object, to the plane object
   my_floor.data.materials.append( my_floors_material_object )
   ```

---

Unfortunately it does not work? Here's the floor I want to create, (the shinny one below the statue)

[image: Floor created using GUI]

Here's what I get with my current script:

[image: Floor created using API]

Seems like it should an easy thing to do, but I'm confused? Here's the a link that I used to get started, [Control Cycles material nodes and material properties in Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/control-cycles-material-nodes-and-material-properties-in-python/23446#23446)

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: As last step you only have to assign the material to the object, see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23433/assign-a-new-material-to-an-object-in-the-scene?rq=1

Comment: Hey poor, thanks alot for the link :) I've added the last step as you advise, and I also found out how to create the materials object using the API from here, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5668/add-nodes-to-material-with-python?rq=1 Unfortunately it still doesn't work ?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Error messages?

Comment: The code runs without any error messages. It just does not do what I expect/want it to do? Basically the material of the floor/plane object is unchanged from **Diffuse BSDF**, (the default), and not **Ansiotropic BSDF** ; which is what I want the script to do. When I run the script, in the the **Surface** panel of the material, the box for the **Surface**, is unchanged from **Diffuse BSDF**  to **Anisotropic BSDF** ??? So I think that's the problem?

Comment: Please check your output Node, it should looks like: `node_output = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeOutputMaterial')`, creating shader code: https://gist.github.com/p2or/fbadce83877a36622720#file-create-anisotropic-py

Comment: Yes !! Thank you very much indeed, I think it works now. I just need to experiment with the default settings, but the basic material seems to be right now ;) How do I accept your answer as the best?

Comment: Sure, can you do it, or do you want me to do it?

Comment: Glad I could help :) Don't delete it, it's helpful for others too, I'll mark it as duplicate.