# Change value of material emission strength from Python console or script

Tags: python, scripting, materials, command-line

I need to programatically modify the value of Material > Surface(Emission) > Strength
[image]

When I change this value manually the output is: `bpy.context.space_data.context = 'DATA'
bpy.data.node_groups["Shader Nodetree"].nodes["Emission"].inputs[1].default_value = 1.2`

[image]

But this command produces an error on the console:

```
>>> bpy.data.node_groups["Shader Nodetree"].nodes["Emission"].inputs[1].default_value = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Shader Nodetree" not found'
```

I also tried accessing a surface attribute of the material but this doesn't work either:

```
>>> bpy.data.materials['light_emit.002'].surface
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Material' object has no attribute 'surface'
```

Besides, where can I find the api reference to try solve these problems by myself in the future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
bpy.data.materials['material_name'].node_tree.nodes["Emission"].inputs[1].default_value = 3 #or any other value
```

Thanks to [this reference](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?321177-How-can-I-add-material-Diffuse-BSDF-to-object-using-python-script)

Comment: What would the equivalent be in Blender 2.8+? I am getting `key "Emission" not found'`

Comment: OK, ^ solved with https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5668/add-nodes-to-material-with-python