# How to add an emission node with a specific color to a material and add that material to an object?

Tags: scripting

So far I have seen [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63288/change-value-of-material-emission-strength-from-python-console-or-script) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23433/how-to-assign-a-new-material-to-an-object-in-the-scene-from-python) both which did not work for me. Currently I have:

```
import bpy

bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].render.engine = "CYCLES"

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=1, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(1.00003, 0.176902, 0.72441),
                                layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
                                        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add()
bpy.ops.material.new()

mat_name = 'Material.001'
bpy.data.materials[mat_name].node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeEmission")
bpy.data.materials[mat_name].node_tree.nodes["Emission"].inputs["Color"].default_value = (1, 0, 0.07, 1)
mat = bpy.data.materials.get(mat_name)
ob = bpy.context.active_object
ob.data.materials[0] = mat
```

When I perform this process in blender the hover text for use nodes in the material->surface section the code is: `bpy.ops.cycles.use_shading_nodes()` and I get: `RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.cycles.use_shading_nodes.poll() failed, context is incorrect` so I'm not sure if I can/have to perform this action or there is a prerequisite to doing it?

I tried starting blender with --debug-wm but this didn't give me more information of how to perform this action in a script.

Is there a better way to show what blender is doing than --debug-wm? Because I can do what I want in blender itself just not in a script.

I also read a lot of api documentations and the tips for blender scripting, but this didn't really help me.

Comment: Thank your for the answer. The important part was removing the other nodes of the material

Comment: IMO the important part from link posted is addressing the material by reference by getting or creating via API with materials collection get and new methods respectively   THe code in Q above adds a new material each time, but only ever sets nodes of  a material named "Material.001" and assigns to slot 0.  Suggest using a unique name for your material then need only create it once.  Remove it to create it agai, other wise get it.  This will avoid creating an endless list of materials whilst testing script.